# IIS 7.5 Warmup Module - Does it really work with Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: iis

I downloaded the IIS 7.5 Application Warmup Module located here: http://www.iis.net/download/applicationwarmup .

I've installed it correctly and have a request hooked up to a test site.

I give it 5 minutes to "do its thing" after an IIS reset. When I make a request to a Sharepoint page (in this case default.aspx), its still dog slow first time round.

After initial page is loaded in browser - I hit f5, and now the 2nd request loads in under 1 second.

So does the IIS warmup module really work? Am I expecting it to do something it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does really work, but best to run requests on the same account that is running app pool and use Windows Authentication.

After this the whole thing worked like a dream.